# No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute for ngControl

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2, ionic4

I'm creating an Ionic social app.  You upload a pic to a firebase backend.  I'm getting the following error message when go to the profile page:
No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute.

So when the page loads, if there's no download url from firebase it should return the image location to use the default button image.  If there's an image in firebase for photo0 then it should use that url.  The NGModel should dynamically change whenever a user uploads or deletes the pic.  But when I load that page I get the no value accessor error.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../../services/user/auth.service';
import { ImageService } from '../../services/image.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';

    public photo0: string;

  
    constructor(private router: Router,
              private authService: AuthService,
              private imageService: ImageService,
              private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {

      this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
      this.userId = user.uid
      console.log('constructoruser', this.userId);
      });
              }
  
  ngOnInit() {
          this.firestore.ref(`/Photos/${ this.userId }/`).child('photo0').getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
          this.photo0 = url;
        }).catch((error) => {
          console.log(error.message);
          this.photo0 = 'assets/img/add-an-image.png';
          console.log(this.photo0);
        });
  }
```

```html
            <div>
                <div [(ngModel)]="photo0">
                    <img src="photo0" (click)="UploadPic0('photo0')"/>
                </div>      
            </div>
```

Comment: Did you import the forms module?  Also, I would think that `this.userId` wouldn't necessarily be available.

Comment: ControlValue accessor is bridge between view and control . Div does not have any controlValueaccessor implemented by default, so you can't place ngModel on div, If you want to use div as a customcontrol then you need to create custom contolValueAcessor Check this:https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor

Comment: Added import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms' to no avail...same error.  I also moved ngModel to:

          <ion-col [(ngModel)]="photo0">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got rid of the error by removing ngModule and just using the following:

```
            <div>
                <img [src]="photo0" (click)="UploadPic0('photo0')"/>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try with:

```
    <div>
        <div *ngIf="photo0 != ''">
            <img [src]="photo0" (click)="UploadPic0('photo0')"/>
        </div>      
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the tag "src" must to receive a component value. You can use `[src]="photo0"` or `src="{{photo0}}"` inside of your img tag.

Comment: Still getting this error when using [src]="photo0":

No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute